# jQuery colorbox only loads once

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have the following problem:

On my website I am using colorbox to display information in a lightbox and I have several divs which you can click to retreive the specific data you want to see. But the jQuery-script I am using only lets the user open a colorbox-screen once and doesn't work after that untill the page is reloaded.

```
$(".items").click(function(){
    $.colorbox({href:$(this).find("a.link",this).attr("href"),width:"900px",maxHeight:"70%"});
    return false;
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give a link to the page is question so we can get a better look at whats going on.  Whats provided isn't really enough info to go by as colorbox is pretty simple in itself, most likely something else is interfering somewhere.  One thing though is there's extra redundancy in your code, the line `$(this).find("a.link",this)` can simply be `$(this).find("a.link")`, you dont need the extra this property set in `.find()` because your already telling jquery to find the a.link inside of the `this` object with `$(this)`

Comment: Try using the .show() to pop it back up again.  I think you might be better served activating the colorbox outside of your click function (although not showing it) and then using .show() or .hide()

Comment: Apparently the second 'this' in $(this).find("a.link",this) was part of the problem while removing it, like Jeff said, solved the problem for Chrome but IE and FF still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your time, the working solution is:

```
$(".items").colorbox({ 
       href:function(){ return $(this).find("a.link").attr("href"); }, 
       width:"900px", 
       maxHeight:"70%" 
});
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to create the colourbox onclick. The plugin does all the event handling for you. Just initialize it this way:

```
$(".items").colorbox({
    href: $(this).find("a.link", this).attr("href"),
    width: "900px",
    maxHeight: "70%"
});
```

See the API and demos at http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: When I use this, my link isn't found (colorbox keeps loading), aside from the code you provided I got this:

<div class='items' title='Details'>
<a href='/details/' class='link'></a>
</div>

Comment: Maybe off topic, but why use .find() at all?  In your context, (this) is the DIV the user clicked, and you seek the href attribute value form an anchor inside the DIV.  The DESCENDANT selector ('div a.items') or the CHILD selector ('div > a.items') would be the better way, no?

Comment: Because there are several divs like this:
<div class='items' title='details1'> 
    <a href='/details/1/' class='link'></a> 
</div>
<div class='items' title='details2'> 
    <a href='/details/2/' class='link'></a> 
</div>
Etc.